# Windows Mobile Application crashes when using Keyboard Hook and Showing a modal Form

Tags: compact-framework

I've setup a keyboard hook to capture the button presses by the user. It works well however, when a modal form is shown (it is actually functioning as a custom Message Box), the application crashes.

I've read that you should never call a blocking function inside a hook; in one of the suggestions I read is to call the hook event in a thread. I've tried this however it still causes the application to crash.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to work around this? or how can anybody suggest another method to capture the button presses without using a keyboard hook

Thanks

Sets and Starts the Hook

```
    public void Start()
    {
        if (m_HookHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            m_HookDelegate = new HookProc(this.HookProcedure);
            m_HookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_HookDelegate, GetModuleHandle(null), 0);

            if (m_HookHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new SystemException("Failed to acquire a valid hook handle");
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the Hook Procedure called back

```
    private int HookProcedure(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        bool handled = false;

        if ((code >= 0) && (wParam == (IntPtr)0x0100))
        {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = new KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT();
            hookStruct.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
            hookStruct.flags = 0;
            hookStruct.scanCode = 0;
            hookStruct.time = 0;
            hookStruct.vkCode = 0;
            hookStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));

            // Let clients determine what to do
            KeyboardHookEventArgs e = new KeyboardHookEventArgs();
            e.HCode = code;
            e.WParam = wParam;
            e.LParam = lParam;
            e.Handled = false;

            KeyBoardInfo keyInfo = new KeyBoardInfo();
            keyInfo.VKCode = hookStruct.vkCode;
            keyInfo.ScanCode = hookStruct.scanCode;

            PublishHookEvent(e, keyInfo);

            handled = e.Handled;
        }

        // Yield to the next hook in the chain
        if (handled)
            return -1;
        else
            return CallNextHookEx(m_HookHandle, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Whenever a hook event is received, the PublishHookEvent will call each registered listener to process the hook event

```
    protected void PublishHookEvent(KeyboardHookEventArgs args, KeyBoardInfo keyBoardInfo)
    {
        if (this.m_KeyboardHookListeners.Count > 0)
        {
            if (args.WParam.ToInt32() == 256)
            {
                IMQKeyboardHookListener hookListener = null;
                for (int idx = 0; idx < this.m_KeyboardHookListeners.Count; idx++)
                {
                    hookListener = this.m_KeyboardHookListeners[idx];
                    if (hookListener != null)
                        hookListener.ProcessKeyboardHookEvent(args, keyBoardInfo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is one of the listeners for the keyboard hook event

```
    public void ProcessKeyboardHookEvent(KeyboardHookEventArgs e, KeyBoardInfo keyBoardInfo)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired == true)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action<KeyboardHookEventArgs, KeyBoardInfo>(ProcessKeyboardHookEvent), new object[] { e, keyBoardInfo });
        }
        else
        {
            Keys keyCode = (Keys)keyBoardInfo.VKCode;

            if (keyCode == Keys.Return)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                this.ProcessKeyboardEvent(keyCode, (char)keyCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything is working well until the MessageBoxForm is called. This is a custom form, added with two buttons OK/CANCEL.

```
    public DialogResult ShowMessageBox(string message)
    {
        this.MessageBoxForm.Message = message;
        DialogResult result = this.MessageBoxForm.ShowDialog();

        return result;
    }
```

The Application Crashes or just hangs during the call to ShowDialog(). I also tried unhooking before calling the ShowDialog(), sometimes this works, sometimes it doesnt. The idea is unhook first to prevent any problems from the blocking call of ShowDialog, then just hook again when the form is closed.

```
    public DialogResult ShowMessageBox(string message)
    {
        KeyboardHook.GetInstance().Unhook();

        this.MessageBoxForm.Message = message;
        DialogResult result = this.MessageBoxForm.ShowDialog();

        KeyboardHook.GetInstance().Hook();

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post some sample code of what you are doing?

Comment: one more thing... when trying to unhook twice, it always returns 1. I understand unhooking the 2nd time should fail, since the handle was already unhooked the first call. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: I don't suppose it could be something so simple as an uninitialized item, could it? Like, is `this.MessageBoxForm` still `null`?

Comment: i dont think so. when i take out the hook - basically not calling the Start() method of the hook - the message form works fine.